# Tor Browser stopped working on my kali?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, torcheck

Tor failed to establish a Tor network connection
Establishing an encrypted directory connection failed

```
04/14/2017 23:19:39.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
04/14/2017 23:21:36.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 10; recommendation warn; host BD6A829255CB08E66FBE7D3748363586E46B3810 at 171.25.193.9:80) 
04/14/2017 23:21:36.600 [WARN] 10 connections have failed: 
04/14/2017 23:21:36.600 [WARN]  10 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
04/14/2017 23:21:40.200 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
04/14/2017 23:21:40.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
04/14/2017 23:21:40.200 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
04/14/2017 23:21:40.200 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set. 
04/14/2017 23:21:42.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
04/14/2017 23:21:42.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
04/14/2017 23:21:42.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
04/14/2017 23:21:42.300 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
04/14/2017 23:22:10.800 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 11; recommendation warn; host 847B1F850344D7876491A54892F904934E4EB85D at 86.59.21.38:443) 
04/14/2017 23:22:10.800 [WARN] 12 connections have failed: 
04/14/2017 23:22:10.800 [WARN]  11 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
04/14/2017 23:22:10.800 [WARN]  1 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
04/14/2017 23:22:18.900 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
04/14/2017 23:22:18.900 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
04/14/2017 23:22:18.900 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
04/14/2017 23:22:18.900 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set. 
04/14/2017 23:28:57.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
04/14/2017 23:28:57.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
04/14/2017 23:28:57.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
04/14/2017 23:28:57.100 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
04/14/2017 23:28:58.000 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 12; recommendation warn; host 7EA6EAD6FD83083C538F44038BBFA077587DD755 at 194.109.206.212:443) 
04/14/2017 23:28:58.000 [WARN] 13 connections have failed: 
04/14/2017 23:28:58.000 [WARN]  12 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
04/14/2017 23:28:58.000 [WARN]  1 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
04/14/2017 23:28:59.600 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
04/14/2017 23:28:59.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
04/14/2017 23:28:59.600 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
04/14/2017 23:28:59.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 13; recommendation warn; host A9406A006D6E7B5DA30F2C6D4E42A338B5E340B2 at 163.172.149.122:443) 
04/14/2017 23:28:59.600 [WARN] 14 connections have failed: 
04/14/2017 23:28:59.600 [WARN]  13 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
04/14/2017 23:28:59.600 [WARN]  1 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
04/14/2017 23:28:59.600 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.
```

What should i do??!

Comment: Does the internet work okay outside of Tor?  Does your ISP perform censorship?